# NotFoundHttpException in routing symfony4

Tags: symfony-4.3

i just created my first symfony 4 application and i wanted to try the routing but it didn't even work it's just stuck to the main route welcome to symfony 4 etc ... neither annotations or routing.yml worked i didn't know where is the problem and when i run debug:router it reads the path and name but not the method name

```
class ArticlesController extends AbstractController
 {

public function hello()
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home")
     */
    return new Response('
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello Symfony 4 World</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
');
}
}
```

Comment: Move the `Route` annotation **before** the method signature

Comment: @msg i solved the problem but thank you anyway